# How to integrate an angular app with mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, angular, spring

I'm writing my first angular application and can't find out how to integrate it with mySql database.

this is a method in controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{employeeId}")
public Employee findEmployeeById(@PathVariable Long employeeId) {
    return employeeService.getById(employeeId);
}
```

a fragment of app.component.ts:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get<Employee>("http://localhost:8080/employees/{employeeId}").subscribe(result => {
        this.employee = result;
        console.log(this.employee);
    });
}
```

Both angular and spring apps launch but at localhost:4200 I just get a white screen.
The annotation @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200") is added.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do that is to have a rest API and request to the backend through POST request or GET request. You should have run nodejs on another port and request to your data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).